# onclick event updating the model attribute but the view not rendering

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-views

In my backbone, i made a onclick event to each model, to update the name.. that works fine. also i am getting the trigger in my view to update the view of the model..

But the view not updating the model.. and the text not at all changing in the html..

my model view:

```
var studentView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName:'li',
    events:{
        'click':"called"
    },
    template:_.template($("#studentTemplate").html()),
    render:function(){
        this.$el.append(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
        this.model.get('scored') > 60 ? this.$el.addClass("active") : null;
        return this;
    },
    called:function(){
        this.model.set('name','text'); // i am setting a name as 'text' for example
    }
});
```

my render View:

```
var studentsView = Backbone.View.extend({
el:$(".page"),
events:{
    "click #highScoreBtn":"showHighScore"
},
initialize:function(){
    this.collection = new collection(student);
    this.render();
    this.collection.on('change', this.renderOne,this);
},
render:function(){
    var that = this;
    _.each(this.collection.models, function(item){
        that.$el.find('ul').append(new studentView({model:item}).render().el);
    })

},
renderOne:function(data){
    this.$el.find('ul').append(new studentView({model:data}).render().el); // appending as new element instead updating the existing one..
}
```

})

so, what is wrong with my code.. or any one correct me this in my jsfiddle..

[here is my jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/3gwebtrain/2Tad7/3/)

Thanks in advance..

Comment: When you click on a studentView li, are you expecting the student's name to change to 'text'? Am I reading your issue correctly?

Comment: Backbone doesn't update the UI when a model's attributes are changed. You need to add code to track the `change` event and render the UI again, or use a framework like: http://rivetsjs.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is works me:

```
var studentView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName:'li',
    events:{
        'click':"called"
    },
    template:_.template($("#studentTemplate").html()),
    initialize:function(){
        this.listenTo(this.model, 'change', this.render);
    },
    render:function(){
        this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
        this.model.get('scored') > 60 ? this.$el.addClass("active") : null;
        return this;
    },
    called:function(){
        this.model.set('name','text');
    }
});
```